# VLAN on main interface (no subinterface)

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, 17.04, interface

I have Ubuntu 17.04. I see on ifconfig that I have eno1 (not eth0). I was created vlan, whose working (I can ping device from that vlan). But actually I see that computer is connected to two networks.

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.1.1.52  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.1.1.255
    inet6 fe80::21fb:881b:982f:a314  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 34:17:eb:cd:2e:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 13464458  bytes 1276532566 (1.2 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 14381729  bytes 996608618 (996.6 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7c00000-f7c20000  

eno1.90: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.66.64.10  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.66.66.255
    inet6 fe80::3617:ebff:fecd:2e0d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 34:17:eb:cd:2e:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1157363  bytes 48659026 (48.6 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1375778  bytes 79131321 (79.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I need to change this settings. PC should work ony on vlan90. I mean vlan 90 will serviced on eno1, not on subinterface eno1.90. Without connecting to "managment network".

Network 10.1.1.0/24 isn't tagged.
Network 10.66.64.0/22 is tagged.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1.90
iface eno1.90 inet static
    address 10.66.64.9
    netmask 255.255.252.0
    network 10.66.64.0
    broadcast 10.66.66.255
    mtu 1500
    vlan-raw-device eno1
```

I disable network manager:

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2017-07-11 08:45:50 CEST; 52s ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 999 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           └─10450 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhcli

lip 11 07:22:42 user NetworkManager[999]: <info>  [1499750562.7541] dhcp4 (eno1):   lease ti
lip 11 07:22:42 user NetworkManager[999]: <info>  [1499750562.7541] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserv
lip 11 07:22:42 user NetworkManager[999]: <info>  [1499750562.7542] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserv
lip 11 07:22:42 user NetworkManager[999]: <info>  [1499750562.7542] dhcp4 (eno1):   domain n
lip 11 07:22:42 user NetworkManager[999]: <info>  [1499750562.7542] dhcp4 (eno1): state chan
lip 11 07:22:42 user dhclient[10450]: bound to 10.1.1.52 -- renewal in 14027 seconds.
lip 11 08:45:50 user systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
lip 11 08:45:50 user NetworkManager[999]: <info>  [1499755550.2979] caught SIGTERM, shutting
lip 11 08:45:50 user NetworkManager[999]: <info>  [1499755550.2987] exiting (success)
lip 11 08:45:50 user systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
```

I was add new configuration on interface:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
#iface eno1 inet dhcp
iface eno1 inet manual
#       address 10.1.1.250
#       netmask 255.255.255.0
#       gateway 10.1.1.253
#       network 10.1.1.0
#       broadcast 10.1.1.255
#       mtu 1500

auto eno1.90
iface eno1.90 inet static
        address 10.66.64.9
        netmask 255.255.252.0
        gateway 10.1.1.1
        network 10.66.64.0
        broadcast 10.66.66.255
        mtu 1500
        vlan-raw-device eno1
```

But after restart NM nothing happened, so I disable it again. In next step I was down interface and then up it again. After this I see it looks start working, because I can't ping devices from 10.1.1.0/24 network. But when I use ifconfig I see the same info like in top.

Now I see that i have some problem with networking service, maybe this is reason of frozen IP address?

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-07-14 16:45:41 CEST; 1min 5
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
 Main PID: 15424 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

lip 14 16:45:34 user systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
lip 14 16:45:41 user ifup[15424]: Set name-type for VLAN subsystem. Sho
lip 14 16:45:41 user ifup[15424]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
lip 14 16:45:41 user ifup[15424]: Failed to bring up eno1.90.
lip 14 16:45:41 user systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exite
lip 14 16:45:41 user systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfac
lip 14 16:45:41 user systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered faile
lip 14 16:45:41 user systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result
```

**2017/07/17**
I was just resolve first problem I think. I use firstly Method #2 from https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-linux-virtual-local-area-network-vlan.html so I have necessary setting. I remove it, using

```
# ifconfig eno1.90 down
# vconfig rem eno1.90
```

After this I down the interface, then networking service restart (It's up without errors) then up interface. Now in `/proc/net/vlan` is created file eno1.90. So I think configuration is now correct. Maybe with main interface is the same, because when I set interface with static option:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
#iface eno1 inet dhcp
#iface eno1 inet manual
iface eno1 inet static
       address 10.1.1.250
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 10.1.1.253
#       network 10.1.1.0
#       broadcast 10.1.1.255
#       mtu 1500

auto eno1.90
iface eno1.90 inet static
        address 10.66.64.9
        netmask 255.255.252.0
        gateway 10.1.1.1
        network 10.66.64.0
        broadcast 10.66.66.255
        mtu 1500
        vlan-raw-device eno1
```

ifconfig still show that I have IP `10.1.1.52`, when it should have `10.1.1.250`. What more, I can ping PC using this two adress (it respond for .52 and .250) :D But I don't know how fix it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` terminal command.

Comment: I don't see where `eno1` is configured. Is it configured in Network Manager? And it is not clear what you want. `eno1.90` is actually your vlan90 on `eno1`. If you disable NM or add `eno1` to `/etc/network/interfaces`, it won't be brought up. And what is `eno1.1390` is supposed to be?

Comment: Maybe this is set on NM, it's a default settings. How check this? VLan I was add using method#2 forom: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-linux-virtual-local-area-network-vlan.html
I want that PC only work in vlan network, and Like you se now it conneting to managment network to (10.1.1.0/24).

Comment: Hi, Can I get any info or any help?

Comment: What do you see "the same"? If you don't do `ifup eno1`, it won't get an address and won't work.

Comment: Do `ifdown eno1`.

Comment: When I do `ifdown eno1` I lost all connections (with vlan 90 too). After 'ifup eno1' connections back, but with the same config (`ifconfig`)

Comment: Where does `eno1` get the IP address if it is not configured?

Comment: One of routers send dhcp frames for network 10.1.1.0/24. This is need to correct working for another devices. But as I understand when I set `iface eno1 inet manual`, Ubuntu should ignore a dhcp frames.

Comment: That's correct. There should be `eno1` in ifconfig, but without an IP address.

Comment: I thing like that too, but as you see it is different. For example I was set static configuration. And after down and up interface I still have address 52 not 250 :D It frustrating me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was resolve problem I think. I use firstly Method #2 from https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-linux-virtual-local-area-network-vlan.html so I have necessary setting. I remove it, using

```
# ifconfig eth0.90 down
# vconfig rem eth0.90
```

After this I down the interface, then networking service restart (It's up without errors) then up interface. Now in `/proc/net/vlan` is created file `eno1.90`. So I think configuration is now correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `eno1`. It is brought up by Network Manger.

You can fix it by disabling Network Manager or by adding

```
iface eno1 inet manual
```

to `/etc/network/interfaces`. NM will not deal with any interface declared in `interfaces`.

To aplly this setting run

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I do like you say, I was disabling NM.
Then i was add in /interfaces:
`auto eno1
#iface eno1 inet dhcp
iface eno1 inet manual
#       address 10.1.1.250
#       netmask 255.255.255.0
#       gateway 10.1.1.253
#       network 10.1.1.0
#       broadcast 10.1.1.255
#       mtu 1500`
But no think happenedafter restart NM. In next step I was stop NM permanently. Nothing happened. Then I was down interface and then up it. And It looks that start working, but I still see the same when I write `ifconfig`. I don't understand this.

Comment: Why do you configure `eno1` if you don't want to use it? And why do you bring it up? I said what to do, but you did all quite different. You needed to add only one line to `interfaces` and don't bring `eno1` up.

Comment: I add only this what you write and another are commented, because i want sometimes connect to network 10.1.1.0/24 (this connection to internet) for example, to install updates.

Comment: maybe I should do somethnik like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128439/good-detailed-explanation-of-etc-network-interfaces-syntax with pre-up and post-down command?

Comment: @Pilot6 having `iface eno1 inet manual` on linux mint does not let the service start